# JAXB through sockets and streams - reader blocks

Tags: java, xml, sockets, networking, jaxb

I'm trying to send java bean instances over a network stream. I want to marshal/unmarshal java instances with `JAXB` and a normal `OutputStream` to push it over the network.

The servers wait at the unmarshal point but the client is already alot further.

Server:

```
inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(this.socket.getInputStream());
outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());
JAXBContext requestContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(this.requestClass);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = requestContext.createUnmarshaller();
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
K request = (K) unmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream); //blocks here
respond();
```

Client:

```
JAXBContext messageContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(message.getClass());
Marshaller marshaller = messageContext.createMarshaller();
out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
marshaller.marshal(message, out);
out.flush();
waitForResponse();// blocks here
```

**EDIT:**    I switched to a normal output stream but it still blocks. Do I have to send some special signal to tell JAXB to stop unmarshalling?    If I close the client output stream the message arrives at the server side.

Comment: The XML reader and writer are unnecessary (you can just use a regular output stream), but should not cause any blocking problems. Please post the class being streamed.

Comment: Thanks, see edit. Can it be that the unmarshaller is waiting for some special signal to stop unmarshalling?

Comment: could you fix the title pls, so others will find this later?

Comment: I just ran some tests and it does indeed look to be an issue with the marshaller/unmarshaller's interaction with the socket stream. I got around it by using intermediate String writers. Will examine this closer when I get home.

Comment: How does your string writer workaround look like?

Comment: @FranzKafka - too much code to post in a comment, I'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I switched to `XMLEventWriter` and `XMLEventWriter` and it works. I've got the feeling `XMLStreamReader` is buggy. It gets stuck on some `skipSpaces()` method. The code of `XMLStreamReader` looks as if it should return as soon as a end of document appears.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that the unmarshaller is choking on socket output stream semantics. My guess would be that it is expecting the stream to be terminated by signalling -1 for the available length, and blocks trying to read forever when it gets 0 instead. Though it may seem hackish, you can get around this problem by using intermediate reader/writers.

Here is an example, based on your code, using intermediary string reader/writer:

Server:

```
final BufferedReader socketReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));
final StringReader dataReader = new StringReader(socketReader.readLine());

JAXBContext requestContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(this.requestClass);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = requestContext.createUnmarshaller();
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
K request = (K) unmarshaller.unmarshal(dataReader);

respond();
```

Client:

```
JAXBContext messageContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(message.getClass());
Marshaller marshaller = messageContext.createMarshaller();
final StringWriter dataWriter = new StringWriter();
marshaller.marshal(message, dataWriter);
out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
out.write(dataWriter.toString());
out.newLine();
out.flush();
waitForResponse();
```

Comment: Thanks, can this not break if the message object has some field with a new line character? I don't think anything during the transformation escapes new lines, because they would be safe in the xml structure.

Comment: If you need to support multilines in the XML then you will need to read and concatenate multiple lines on the server side, prior to unmarshalling.

Comment: "it is expecting the stream to be terminated by signalling -1 for the available length". What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, i think the xml parser waits for end of stream before finishing (it doesn't give up just because it has received the "end" of the xml).

one option would be to put some stream wrapper on top of the socket stream which returns -1 after all the xml data has been read.  however, figuring out when you have reached that point is a non-trivial situation.

another option would be to create your own XMLEventReader which wraps a delegate XMLEventReader and ends after the closing xml event is received.

[This](http://marc.info/?l=xerces-j-user&m=117066258314001&w=2) is another solution (custom "end of stream" marks).