# JAXB through sockets Unmarshaling issue

Tags: java, sockets, jaxb, unmarshalling

Sorry guys that i repeat a topik. But i do not understand an answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9598909/1404852 
"Kafka" said that he fix unmarshaling block by using XMLEventWriter. Cause suggestion to write in Stream Strings and then concate them to unmarshal not suitable for me.

I have such code.

```
public class InputThread implements Runnable {
    private BufferedReader in;  
    private String fserver; // = CharBuffer.allocate(0);
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(InputThread.class);
    private JAXBContext jaxbContext;
    private Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller;
    private XMLProtocol protocol;

    public InputThread(Socket fromserver, BufferedReader in) throws IOException, JAXBException {
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(XMLProtocol.class);
        jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        this.in = in;
        new Thread(this);
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (in.ready()) 

                    protocol = (XMLProtocol) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(in);


            }
        }
    }

}
```

Or on Server side i should to insert end of stream? But i think that JAXB can doing anything...

Comment: What exception are you seeing?

Comment: It blocks. Cause it can not see the end of the Stream.

Comment: Sorry i get exception. DefaultValidationEventHandler: [FATAL_ERROR]: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Answer (score 0):

Either the stream can encode the length up front, it can end with a special character like EOF or server can close the connection. If you encode the length up front, you probably need to construct some sort of special input stream that closes itself after that many characters. That is like HTTP with the Content-Length header and pipelining. If you end with a special character like EOF you have to treat that character as reserved. Also, as above you would need a special input stream. This time it was close when it reads the special character. It can't appear in your data because it is now a metacharacter. And closing the connection is like HTTP without pipelining.

Comment: Hmm so on the server side. after marshaling into output stream i should write EOF?